# Generate SaS token for Azure Storage Account blob Container

Tags: azure, apim

I am trying to generate SaS token for Storage Account blob container in Azure APIM policy.
But the SaS token is not getting generated correctly as it is throwing Authentication failed error.
Below is the snippet from the policy.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.
Please help.

I tried the below code

```
<set-variable name="accessKey" value="{{accessKey}}" />
<set-variable name="resourcePath" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("containerName"))" />
<set-variable name="x-ms-date" value="@(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R"))" />
<set-variable name="x-ms-version" value="2022-11-02" />
<set-variable name="signedPermissions" value="rw" />
<set-variable name="signedStart" value="2023-11-22T06:35:21Z" />
<set-variable name="signedExpiry" value="2023-11-23T06:35:21Z" />
<set-variable name="signedResource" value="c" />
<set-variable name="signedVersion" value="2021-10-04" />
<set-variable name="canonicalizedResource" value="@{
    return string.Format("/{0}/{1}",(string)context.Variables["storageAccount"],    
    string)context.Variables["resourcePath"]);
    }" />
<set-variable name="signedProtocol" value="https" />
<set-variable name="stringToSign" value="@{
    return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}",
    (string)context.Variables["signedPermissions"],                
    (string)context.Variables["signedStart"],
    (string)context.Variables["signedExpiry"],
    (string)context.Variables["canonicalizedResource"],
    (string)context.Variables["signedProtocol"],
    (string)context.Variables["signedVersion"],
    (string)context.Variables["signedResource"]) ;
    }" />
<set-variable name="signature" value="@{
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hasher = new  
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String((string)context.Variables["accessKey"]));
    return   Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)context.Variables["stringToSign"])));
            }" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `StringToSign` format as per latest version [2022-11-02](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#version-2020-12-06-and-later).

You can use the below policy to generate the SAS token.

**Policy**-

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- extract parameters from URL -->
        <set-variable name="containerName" value="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["containerName"])" />
        <set-variable name="accessKey" value="{access_key}" />
        <set-variable name="expiryInSeconds" value="3600" />
        <set-variable name="storageAccount" value="{Storage_account_name}" />
        <set-variable name="x-ms-date" value="@(DateTime.UtcNow)" />
        <set-variable name="signedPermissions" value="r" />
        <set-variable name="signedService" value="c" />
        <set-variable name="signedStart" value="@(((DateTime)context.Variables["x-ms-date"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))" />
        <set-variable name="signedExpiry" value="@(((DateTime)context.Variables["x-ms-date"]).AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt32((string)context.Variables["expiryInSeconds"])).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))" />
        <set-variable name="signedProtocol" value="https" />
        <set-variable name="signedVersion" value="2022-11-02" />
        <set-variable name="canonicalizedResource" value="@{
            return string.Format("/blob/{0}/{1}",
                (string)context.Variables["storageAccount"],
                (string)context.Variables["containerName"]
            );
        }" />
        <set-variable name="signedIP" value="" />
        <set-variable name="signedIdentifier" value="" />
        <set-variable name="signedResource" value="c" />
        <set-variable name="signedSnapshotTime" value="" />
        <set-variable name="signedEncryptionScope" value="" />
        <set-variable name="rscc" value="" />
        <set-variable name="rscd" value="" />
        <set-variable name="rsce" value="" />
        <set-variable name="rscl" value="" />
        <!-- Build the string to form signature. -->
        <set-variable name="StringToSign" value="@{
            return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}\n{8}\n{9}\n{10}\n{11}\n{12}\n{13}\n{14}\n",
                (string)context.Variables["signedPermissions"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedStart"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedExpiry"],
                (string)context.Variables["canonicalizedResource"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedIdentifier"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedIP"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedProtocol"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedVersion"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedResource"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedSnapshotTime"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedEncryptionScope"],
                (string)context.Variables["rscc"],
                (string)context.Variables["rscd"],
                (string)context.Variables["rsce"],
                (string)context.Variables["rscl"]
            );
        }" />
        <!-- Build/Hash the signature. -->
        <set-variable name="Signature" value="@{
            byte[] SignatureBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)context.Variables["StringToSign"]);
            System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hasher = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String((string)context.Variables["accessKey"]));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(SignatureBytes));
        }" />
        <!-- Form the sasToken. -->
        <set-variable name="SasToken" value="@{
            return string.Format("sv={0}&sr={1}&sp={2}&st={3}&se={4}&spr={5}&sig={6}",
                (string)context.Variables["signedVersion"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedService"],
                (string)context.Variables["signedPermissions"],
                System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode((string)context.Variables["signedStart"]),
                System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode((string)context.Variables["signedExpiry"]),
                (string)context.Variables["signedProtocol"],
                System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode((string)context.Variables["Signature"])
            );
        }" />
        <!-- Form the complete Url. -->
        <set-variable name="FullUrl" value="@{
            return string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}/?{2}",
                (string)context.Variables["storageAccount"],
                (string)context.Variables["containerName"],
                (string)context.Variables["SasToken"]
            ).Replace("+", "%2B");
        }" />
        <set-variable name="metadataUrl" value="@{
            return string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}/?comp=metadata&{2}",
                (string)context.Variables["storageAccount"],
                (string)context.Variables["containerName"],
                (string)context.Variables["SasToken"]
            ).Replace("+", "%2B");
        }" />
        <!-- Check existance of the blob before returning 200 OK with sas token. -->
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="blobMetadata" timeout="30" ignore-error="false">
            <set-url>@((string)context.Variables["metadataUrl"])</set-url>
            <set-method>GET</set-method>
        </send-request>
        <choose>
            <!-- Check active property in response -->
            <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["blobMetadata"]).StatusCode == 404)">
                <!-- Return 404 Not Found with http-problem payload -->
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="404" reason="Not Found" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@{
                        return new JObject(
                                new JProperty("error", "not_found"),
                                new JProperty("error_description", "No data could be found for the given parameters."),
                                new JProperty("timestamp", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"))
                            ).ToString();
                    }</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <!-- return response -->
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@{
                        var fullUrl = ((string)context.Variables["FullUrl"]);
                        var remainingValidDuration = ((Convert.ToDateTime((string)context.Variables["signedExpiry"])) - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;
                        
                        return new JObject(
                                new JProperty("url", fullUrl),
                                new JProperty("expiresIn", Math.Floor(remainingValidDuration).ToString()),
                                new JProperty("timestamp", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"))
                            ).ToString();
                    }</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

***I am able to get the URL along with the SAS token in it.***

[image]
[image]

I can get the content of every blob which are there in the specified container as shown below.

[image]

***References***-

[Generate a SAS token from within an APIM policy - Maxim Braekman](https://mbraekman.github.io/2021/04/27/APIM-Generate-SAS-token/#full-policy).

Comment: Thanks, I was using wrong version and parameter combination to form the string to sign.
It did resolve my issue.